# Log4j2 Configuration - Daily Rolling with Max Files

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

So, I always have trouble with setting up lo4j - I can never seem to fully grasp what my configuration actually means.  That being said, I'm trying to set up log4j2 on a new application, and I really don't want to, at this point, spend time trying to figure this out.

What I need to do, for my application, is to set up log4j2 such that it logs to both a file and the console (i.e., standard out).  Along with that, I need to configure it so that it creates a new log file every day and only keeps ten at a time.

Ideally, I would like to use asynchronous logging, with a system-wide default threshold for logging set at ERROR.

Firstly, here's the configuration I have right now, which doesn't handle the rolling or max number of files constraints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug" monitorInterval="600">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="web-services" fileName="web-services-log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
        </File>
        <Async name="ASYNC">
            <AppenderRef ref="web-services" />
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
        </Async>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <logger name="log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header" level="fatal"
            additivity="false" />
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="ASYNC" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

So, a couple of additional questions, if I may:

1.) What is the difference between the `<Configuration status="log-level">` and `<Root level="debug">` levels?  What if I had the root one set to ERROR and the left the parent Configuration node level set to DEBUG?

2.) Many times, I want specific packages to be set to DEBUG, while the rest of the application is set to ERROR.  Am I correct in understanding I can do this by simply specifying additional loggers like I have for `<logger name="log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header" level="fatal" additivity="false" />`?

3.) If I wanted to have exceptions log to their own file, just for errors and exceptions, but also to the standard appenders, how might I accomplish this?  From what I have read, exception handling loggers should be synchronous so that events are not lost.

Oh, and if it matters, here's the pom config for my log4j2 dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta9</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta9</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

A1. The configuration status level is for the log4j **internal** status log. If you set it to `DEBUG`, log4j will print information about the loggers and appenders it configured to `System.out` at startup time. It is useful to determine any configuration problems. Whatever value you set it to will not affect the application logging.

A2. Every Logger that you configure needs to be linked to a destination Appender with an `AppenderRef` element. For example:

```
<logger name="log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header" level="fatal" additivity="false">
  <AppenderRef ref="ASYNC" />
</logger>
```

A3. Starting from your current config, add another File Appender, let's call it "error-file". Now add another logger with level `ERROR` that you link to the "error-file" appender. To ensure that this logger sees all events, you give it the name of the top-level package of your application. For example, if your application uses package com.mycompany.myproject.module.SomeClass, you could name the logger "com.mycompany.myproject", or even just "com". If you have multiple top-level packages you can declare an ERROR level logger for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your most initial question »… Daily Rolling with Max Files«: Unfortunally, this isn't implemented within the current version of log4j2 (nor in beta9 neither in rc1).

See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-435